# Calendar Extendar is not showing Starting Date of one textbox to selected date of another textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'll try to simplify my query as much as possible. I am using to textboxes one is for starting date and one is for ending date. starting date is working well but in ending date it's start date should be selected date of starting date textbox.

Here is my Code.

```
protected void txtSRPStartDate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtSRPEndingDate_CalendarExtender.StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtSRPStartDate_CalendarExtender.SelectedDate);
    txtSRPEndingDate_CalendarExtender.EndDate = DateTime.Now;
}
```

In this code when i'd debugged the code it's showing me selected date of starting date textbox as `null`.

Any Suggestion please.

Comment: `.SelectedDate` is _already_ a `DateTime`. You don't need to use `Convert.ToDateTime` with it.

Comment: I'd tried as you said but still result is null . :(

Answer (score 0):

[Quote](http://forums.asp.net/p/1174158/1972766.aspx) from the first link in a google search.

> The SelectedDate of the CalendarExtender is just to set an initial
>   selected date on the calendar.
>
> You can't use is to get the last selected date by the user. The
>   selectedDate property isn't updated to the date the user selects!!

So instead, you need to get the date from the `textbox` not the calendar extender.

```
protected void txtSRPStartDate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtSRPEndingDate_CalendarExtender.StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtSRPStartDate.Text);
    txtSRPEndingDate_CalendarExtender.EndDate = DateTime.Now;
}
```